# Javascript insert into table using loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I am working on the below code. The user selects an image and clicks on the data table button. On clicking the  button the respective table fields are filled

```js
function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  cell1.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('img_add').files[0].name;
  cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById('img_add').files[0].size;
  cell4.innerHTML = '<span class="p-viewer"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>';

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title>Datatable form</title>
    
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    
  
  <div style="text-align: center;padding-top: 2rem;">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="img_add">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Data Table</button>
  </div>
    
    <img>
    <div class="col-10 center" style="margin: auto;text-align: center;">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered border-primary ">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Sr No.</th>
            <th scope="col">Image Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Image Size (bytes))</th>
            <th scope="col">View</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to do it line by line but I  want to add it via a loop. How to achieve it
Any help would  be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well first you need to create the table data. You should create it as a JSON string. Next you need to call the **myFunction()** inside a for loop, and pass it the JSON data as parameter. See this [description of JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

Comment: Any other way except JSON?

Comment: Well JSON is the standard format for storing data in JavaScript. It can be easily processed within a for loop. Another option is to use JavaScript arrays. See: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp